# VennDiagram create list of vennCounts

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I have a table like this:

```
> updownregtable                                                           
             PIM WDR MYC OBX                                               
ILMN_1651282 0   0   0   0                                                 
ILMN_1651354 0   0   0   0                                                 
ILMN_1651358 0   0   0   0                                                 
ILMN_1656638 0   0   0   0                                                 
ILMN_1657235 0   0   0   0                                                 
ILMN_1657639 -1  0   0   0
```

The rownames are codes for genes. The colnames are transfections in a cell.

I make a vennDiagram with the functions in the following link:
http://bioinfo-mite.crb.wsu.edu/Rcode/Venn.R

Before making the vennDiagram, vennCounts results gives this output:

```
> vennCounts(regulationtable)
      PIM WDR MYC OBX Counts
 [1,]   0   0   0   0    740
 [2,]   0   0   0   1      5
 [3,]   0   0   1   0      1
 [4,]   0   0   1   1      0
 [5,]   0   1   0   0      4
 [6,]   0   1   0   1      1
 [7,]   0   1   1   0      0
 [8,]   0   1   1   1      0
 [9,]   1   0   0   0      6
[10,]   1   0   0   1      0
[11,]   1   0   1   0      0
[12,]   1   0   1   1      0
[13,]   1   1   0   0      1
[14,]   1   1   0   1      0
[15,]   1   1   1   0      0
[16,]   1   1   1   1      0
```

Now I want to create per row a list within all the genenames stored in that group. e.g. like this:

Group 1 - creates a list with 740 genenames

Group 2 - creates a list with 5 genenames

Group 3 - creates a list with 1 genenames

Group 5 - creates a list with 4 genenames

Group 6 - creates a list with 1 genenames

Group 9 - creates a list with 6 genenames

Group 13 - creates a list with 1 genename.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution. Basically it involves converting the matrix to a character vector, since there are convenient functions for matching text strings.

```
## create an example matrix - analagous to your 'updownregtable'                                                                               
nc <- 4
nr <- 1000
M <- matrix(rbinom(nr*nc,1,0.5),
            nrow = nr, ncol = nc,
            dimnames = list(sapply(1:nr, function(i) paste(sample(letters,5),collapse='')),paste('V',1:nc)))
## function for converting rows of a matrix to lines of text                                                                                   
matrix2text <- function(y) apply(y,1,function(x)paste(x,collapse=','))
## unique entries - analagous to the first four columns of your matrix                                                                         
## vennCounts(regulationtable)                                                                                                                 
Mu <- matrix2text(unique(M))
names(Mu) <- NULL
## convert the full matrix to text                                                                                                             
Mc <- matrix2text(M)
## find the matching groups                                                                                                                    
matching.groups <- sapply(Mu,function(x)names(grep(x,Mc,value=TRUE)))
## here are the counts per group                                                                                                               
counts.per.group <- sapply(matching.groups,length)
```